# Plotting ellipses with transparency with OpenCV

Tags: opencv, transparency, transparent, rgba

I am currently plotting ellipses in a white background as well as X and Y axis with opencv like this:

```
Mat image = Mat::zeros(size,size, CV_8UC3);
image.setTo(Scalar(255,255,255));   /* White background */

/* Draw Axis */
line(image, 
        Point(originX, 0),                              /*Point 1*/
        Point(originX, size),                           /*Point 2*/
        Scalar(colorAxis.B,colorAxis.G,colorAxis.R),    /*Color*/
        1,                                              /*Thickness*/
        8);                                             /*lineType*/

line(image, 
        Point(0, originY),                              /*Point 1*/
        Point(size, originY),                           /*Point 2*/
        Scalar(colorAxis.B,colorAxis.G,colorAxis.R),    /*Color*/
        1,                                              /*Thickness*/
        8); 

for(i=0; i<numEllipses; i++)
{
    ellipse(image,
            Point(originX + dataEllipse[k].center[0]*ppu, originY - dataEllipse[k].center[1]*ppu),
            Size(dataEllipse[k].axis[0]*ppu, dataEllipse[k].axis[1]*ppu),
            -dataEllipse[k].angle,
            0,
            360,
            Scalar(colorEllipse.B, colorEllipse.G, colorEllipse.R),
            -1,
            CV_FILLED);
}

imshow("Result", image);
waitKey(1);
```

The this is that there are an N number of ellipses and they overlap. Plus there is a weight value that corresponds to a color (from blue to red). I would like to use this weight value to use it as an alpha parameter as well.

For what I've seen it is possible to use an addWeigth function but it is between two images and I would like to do it with the ellipses. Is there any way to do it or I would have to have one image per ellipse and use addWeigth with image0 and image1, then (image0 and image1) and image2 and so on?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: render each ellipse to a different image and use addWeighted on those images!

Comment: addWeight takes two images at the time, right? If it is like that, I would have to have the background with the axis in image[0], and from image[1] to image[numEllipses] each ellipse and then do in a loop addWeight(image[0], image[n])?

Comment: That didn't work....I end up with the transparency of the last ellipse for all of them

Comment: looks like addweighted doesnt support masks... I'll add an answer with manual summation. You could adapt openCV free source code to use blending during ellipse drawing directly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple sample program which uses temporary ellipse images for drawing transparent ellipses.

Note that weight = 1 means that the ellipse isn't transparent but solid, so nothing "under" that ellipse is visible anymore. And the order of drawing does make a difference!

```
int main()
{
    //cv::Mat input = cv::imread("../inputData/Lenna.png");
    cv::Mat background = cv::Mat(512,512, CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(255,255,255));

    std::vector<cv::Point2f> centers;
    std::vector<cv::Scalar> colors;
    std::vector<cv::Size> axes;
    std::vector<float> angles;
    std::vector<float> weights;

    // make sure that there are same number of entries in each vector.
    centers.push_back(cv::Point2f(255, 255));
    centers.push_back(cv::Point2f(275, 255));
    centers.push_back(cv::Point2f(255, 275));
    centers.push_back(cv::Point2f(275, 275));
    centers.push_back(cv::Point2f(255, 225));
    centers.push_back(cv::Point2f(225, 225));

    colors.push_back(cv::Scalar(255,0,0));
    colors.push_back(cv::Scalar(0,255,0));
    colors.push_back(cv::Scalar(0,0,255));
    colors.push_back(cv::Scalar(0,0,0));
    colors.push_back(cv::Scalar(0,0,0));
    colors.push_back(cv::Scalar(0,255,0));

    axes.push_back(cv::Size(128,128));
    axes.push_back(cv::Size(128,128));
    axes.push_back(cv::Size(128,128));
    axes.push_back(cv::Size(128,128));
    axes.push_back(cv::Size(128,128));
    axes.push_back(cv::Size(128,128));

    angles.push_back(0);
    angles.push_back(0);
    angles.push_back(0);
    angles.push_back(0);
    angles.push_back(0);
    angles.push_back(0);

    // weight 0 means completely transparent = invible. weight 1 means completely solid = will overwrite everything else
    weights.push_back(0.5f); // half transparent
    weights.push_back(0.5f);
    weights.push_back(0.5f);
    weights.push_back(1.0f); // solid
    weights.push_back(0.3f); // quite transparent
    weights.push_back(0.3f); // quite transparent

    // ORDER DOES MATTER! 
    // printing a transparent ellipse over a solid ellipse will make the transparent ellipse partly visible, but printing the solid ellipse over anything will make only the solid ellipse visible
    // you could however sort ellipses before printing so that more solid ones are more in the background for example

    int thickness = 5;

    for(unsigned int i=0; i<centers.size(); ++i)
    {
        cv::Mat temporaryEllipse = cv::Mat::zeros(background.rows, background.cols, background.type()); // same size and type as background;
        cv::Mat temporaryMask = cv::Mat::zeros(background.rows, background.cols, CV_8UC1); // empty single channel 8bit mask

        // draw ellipse to temporary
        cv::ellipse(temporaryEllipse, centers[i], axes[i], angles[i], 0, 360, colors[i], thickness);

        // draw same ellipse to mask
        cv::ellipse(temporaryMask, centers[i], axes[i], angles[i], 0, 360, 255, thickness);

        for(int y=0; y<temporaryEllipse.rows; ++y)
            for(int x=0; x<temporaryEllipse.cols; ++x)
            {
                // only blend pixel that belong to the ellipse!
                if(temporaryMask.at<unsigned char>(y,x))
                {
                    cv::Vec3b ellipsePixel = temporaryEllipse.at<cv::Vec3b>(y,x);
                    cv::Vec3b backgroundPixel = background.at<cv::Vec3b>(y,x);

                    float weight = weights[i];
                    cv::Vec3b blendedPixel = weight*ellipsePixel + (1-weight)*backgroundPixel;

                    // update result
                    background.at<cv::Vec3b>(y,x) = blendedPixel;
                }
            }
    }


    cv::imshow("input", background);
    cv::imwrite("../outputData/TransparentEllipses.png", background);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

and here drawn with a thickness of 15

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code with just two filled ellipses, one red and one blue with sizes (1,2) and (2,1) with 0.8 weight for the red and 0.2 for the blue one. Therefore, I should (or I want to) end with the red ellipse @ 0.8 and the blue one @ 0.2. And where they overlap it should be a mix between red and blue, right? Plus if I understood correctly your code, the first ellipse will be plotted completely but when the second one is plotted, the parts that only overlap between them will be shown. Am I right? 
I got your code and I ended up with this:

```
        cv::Mat background = cv::Mat(size,size, CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(255,255,255));
    int color[nEll][3] = {{255,0,0},{0,0,255}}, y,x, s[nEll][2]={{2,1},{1,2}};
    float weights[nEll] = {0.8, 0.2};
    for(i=0; i<nEll; i++)
    {
        Mat temporaryEllipse = Mat::zeros(size,size, CV_8UC3);
        Mat temporaryMask = Mat::zeros(size,size,CV_8UC1);

        // draw ellipse to temporary
        ellipse(temporaryEllipse,
                Point(originX + 0.5*ppu, originY - 0.5*ppu),
                Size(s[i][0]*ppu, s[i][1]*ppu),
                0,//angle
                0,
                360,
                Scalar(color[i][0], color[i][1], color[i][2]),
                -1,
                CV_FILLED);

        // draw same ellipse to mask
        ellipse(temporaryMask,
                Point(originX + 0.5*ppu, originY - 0.5*ppu),
                Size(s[i][0]*ppu, s[i][1]*ppu),
                0,//angle
                0,
                360,
                Scalar(color[i][0], color[i][1], color[i][2]),
                -1,
                CV_FILLED);

        for(y=0; y<temporaryEllipse.rows; ++y)
        {
            for(int x=0; x<temporaryEllipse.cols; ++x)
            {
                // only blend pixel that belong to the ellipse
                if(temporaryMask.at<unsigned char>(y,x))
                {
                    cv::Vec3b ellipsePixel = temporaryEllipse.at<cv::Vec3b>(y,x);
                    cv::Vec3b backgroundPixel = background.at<cv::Vec3b>(y,x);

                    cv::Vec3b blendedPixel = weights[i]*ellipsePixel + (1-weights[i])*backgroundPixel;

                    // update result
                    background.at<cv::Vec3b>(y,x) = blendedPixel;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    cv::imshow("input", background);
```

But I got just the last ellipse shown with weight=1.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: you have to write value >0 to mask. Mask is a single channel matrix, so try `ellipse(temporaryMask,
                Point(originX + 0.5*ppu, originY - 0.5*ppu),
                Size(s[i][0]*ppu, s[i][1]*ppu),
                0,//angle
                0,
                360,
                Scalar(255),
                -1,
                CV_FILLED);

Comment: in addition, first weight = 0.8 means that you'll the see white background shining through the first ellipse, not sure if that is intended.

Comment: and not sure if I understand it right. If you have a background with colorB= (255,255,255) and you have 2 ellipses, one with color1= (0,0,255) and one with color2= (255,0,0) and you draw the first with weight1= 0.8 and the second one with weight2= 0.2 then you'll end up with 4 different regions: regionA=only background; regionB= only ellipse1; regionC= only ellipse2; regionD= ellipse1&ellipse2. Then regionA=[255,255,255]; regionB=[51,51,204];  regionC=[51,204,204]; regionD=[92,41,163]

Comment: I cannot believe I missed that with the temporaryMask!. That worked now flawlesless.
And as you said, it is not intended for the first ellipse to the white background shining....plus I have a grid and X and Y axis plotted before plotting the ellipses....

Comment: when you use transparency that touches the background, the background will always shine through (because the ellipse is transparent). If you only want to blend regions that don't touch the background, you'll need more complex blending conditions. but that can all be done by using masks. for example you could hold an initially empty mask for the background/foreground, too, filling it whenever you draw an ellipse, so you only use the transparency sum at pixels where the foreground mask is set, too.

Comment: This is working flawlessly now! It even blends with the axis and grid that I plot before so you kind of see it behind the ellipses!

if I'm reading the values of the ellipses at certain frequency (~10 or 20 Hz), would cv::imwrite affect this? I mean, it is writting on disk a lot and quite fast.....and I might miss incoming data.

Comment: imwrite of jpeg or png might be too slow. if compression is fast enough you can compute how many MB/sec will be written (look at your average file sizes) and look at the writing speed of your hard drive.

Comment: I believe in this case would be to save the array 'background' in a buffer to ram and then save all after receiving the inputs......
As I don't know the input number, would it be a very bad idea to use something like  Mat buffer[5000} = Mat::zeros(size,size, CV_8UC3); ?

Comment: if you have enough RAM to hold them all just use a std::vector<cv::Mat>

Comment: Yes, RAM shouldn't be a problem as each image is fairly small (800x800) pixels......with std::vector<cv::Mat> I believe I use push_back as you did. Is there another function to know how many pushes I did?

Comment: .size() gives you the current number of elements. you can access elements with [index] or with .at(index)

Comment: awesome! I still have to google it, but I guess from that std::vector<cv::Mat> it will be also possible to save them in a .avi file....I'll get back to this tomorrow maybe....or monday :). Thanks for all your help!

Comment: you can use cv::VideoWriter to do so :)

Comment: Everything worked great! Thank you very much for all your help!

Comment: nice to hear. If you answer helped you, fell free to upvote ;)

Comment: I did but as I have less than 15 reputation it will not be display until I earn the reputation....

Comment: Thanks! I didnt know that :D